# Shows "[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException" for data driven(excel File) API Automation test(Rest Assured)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, data-driven, rest-assured

It throws a java.lang.NullPointerException, but why it shows that, I could not find.
Here is my code.

> ExcelUtil

```
package Utils;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelUtil {
    
    public static FileInputStream fi;
    public static FileOutputStream fo;
    public static XSSFWorkbook wb;
    public static XSSFSheet ws;
    public static XSSFRow row;
    public static XSSFCell cell;
    
    public static int getRowCount(String excelPath, String sheetName) throws IOException {
        fi= new FileInputStream(excelPath);
        wb= new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
        ws= wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        int rowcount= ws.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println(rowcount);
        wb.close();
        fi.close();
        return rowcount;
    }
    
    public static int getCellCount(String excelPath, String sheetName, int rownum) throws IOException {
        fi= new FileInputStream(excelPath);
        wb= new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
        ws= wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        row= ws.getRow(rownum);
        int cellcount= row.getLastCellNum();
        wb.close();
        fi.close();
        return cellcount;
    }
    
    public static String getCellData(String excelPath, String sheetName, int rownum, int colnum) throws IOException {
        fi= new FileInputStream(excelPath);
        wb= new XSSFWorkbook(fi);
        ws= wb.getSheet(sheetName);
        row= ws.getRow(rownum);
        cell= row.getCell(colnum);
        String data;
        try {
            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
            String cellData = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            return cellData;
            
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            data="";
            System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
            System.out.println(exp.getCause());
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        wb.close();
        fi.close();
        return data;
    }

}
```

> DataDrivenPostRequest

```
package DataDrivenAPICollection;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

import All_Utils.ExcelUtils;
import Utils.ExcelUtil;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;

public class DataDrivenPostRequest {
    
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String excelPath = path + "./API_Data/TestData.xlsx";
    String sheetName = "Data1";
    
    ExcelUtils excel = new ExcelUtils(excelPath, sheetName);
    
    @Test(dataProvider="empdataprovider")
    public void PostRequestTest(String Name, String Image, String Age, String DateofBirth, String Mobile, String Email, String Password) {
    request.put("Name", Name);
    request.put("Image", Image);
    request.put("Age", Age);
    request.put("DateofBirth", DateofBirth);
    request.put("Mobile", Mobile);
    request.put("Email", Email);
    request.put("Password", Password);
    given().
        header("Content-Type","application/json").
        contentType(ContentType.JSON).
        accept(ContentType.JSON).
        body(request.toString()).
    when().
        post("https://almashossain.com/APP/VIEWS/API.php?RequestTitle=EmployeeRegistration").
    then().
        statusCode(200).
        log().all();
        
    }
    
    @DataProvider(name="empdataprovider")
    String [][] getEmpdata() throws IOException{
        String excelPath = "./API_Data/TestData.xlsx";
        String sheetName = "Data1";
        
        ExcelUtil excel = new ExcelUtil();
        
        int rownum = excel.getRowCount(excelPath, sheetName);
        int colcount = excel.getCellCount(excelPath, sheetName,1);
        
        String empdata[][] = new String[rownum][colcount]; 
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= rownum; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colcount; j++) {
                empdata[i-1][j] = excel.getCellData(excelPath, sheetName, i, j);
                
            }
            
        }
        
        return(empdata);
    }
}
```

> Error messages:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Utils.ExcelUtil.getRowCount(ExcelUtil.java:27)
    at DataDrivenAPICollection.DataDrivenPostRequest.getEmpdata(DataDrivenPostRequest.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:76)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:145)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:797)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:740)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:38)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:789)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED: PostRequestTest
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:49)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:145)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:797)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:740)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.handleParameters(ParameterHandler.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.ParameterHandler.createParameters(ParameterHandler.java:38)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:789)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Utils.ExcelUtil.getRowCount(ExcelUtil.java:27)
    at DataDrivenAPICollection.DataDrivenPostRequest.getEmpdata(DataDrivenPostRequest.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:76)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodNoCheckedException(MethodInvocationHelper.java:45)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have correct sheet name. As you can see in stacktrace, error happens in ExcelUtil line 27. Debug/Print the sheet name to see if the value is correct.

Comment: Yeah, I solved the problem. Some how my modified sheet name was not saved properly.